# Required informations to integrations of azure b2c with Windows ADFS

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-ad-b2c

1. Which type of information is required for integrations of Azure B2C with Windows ADFS
2. I already created Azure B2C app, now I want to know point num 1 information
3. Azure b2c auth mode is openid.

Comment: Did you check the doc @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp follow the doc if you have any issues while integrating ping here. I can help you

Comment: Worth pointing out that the integration in  that link is SAML.